# Having problems building my login-function, cant store sessions (php)

Tags: php, session

I am a Beginner. Right now I am trying to build a simple Login/Register-System to learn.

It worked once, but not anymore and I cant figure out where im going wrong. Slowly my Code becomes Spaghetti.

What I want: 
LOGIN-System that starts a Session after logging in. But the session is not working! Please beware that all the echos are ugly but just for me to check right now!

My HTML CODE:

```
//Check if class responds
$user->classtest();

session_start();

//Login-Function
if($user->checkSession()) { 

echo "Session is okay";

} else {

    if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['upass'])) {

    $name = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['upass'];

        if($user->checkPW($name,$pass)) {

        $user->startSession($name,$pass);

        } else {

        echo "Your Login is wrong, please try again";
        $user->loginForm();    
        }

    } else {

    echo "<br>You are not logged in. Please login!";    
    $user->loginForm();

    }
}
```

Here are the function from the classes:
Starting the Session:

```
    public function startSession($uname,$upass) {

    $userData = $this->getUserData($uname);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $userData[0]["username"];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $userData[0]["password"];

        echo "<br>You are logged in and we started the session ";
        echo "<br>Username: " . $_SESSION['username'] . "<br>";
        echo "<br>Password: " . $_SESSION['password'] . "<br>";    
        return true;    

}
```

and my function that should check if there is a Session:

```
 public function checkSession() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Now, although my startSession function gives me the $_SESSION['username'] correctly after submitting the login-form the checkSession() Function always gives me false.

Sorry for the not perfect code etc. Im a real beginner still figuring things out!

Comment: Have you done `session_start` on the page where `checkSession` is being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just init the session with `session_start();` on the top of your file.

Or - if necessary - in the construct function of your class:

```
function __construct() { session_start(); }
```

Please be aware of having output before initialise Session (or setting cookies also).

Comment: Thank you, i tried both now. Still my checkSession() wont check anything.

Comment: Try to set session_data to `1` only for debugging. `$_SESSION['username'] = $_SESSION['password'] = 1;`

Comment: This works. If I add the code into my html my checkSession() tells me that everything is fine.

Comment: And if you add this code into `startSession()` method? You should also try `var_dump($userData = $this->getUserData($uname), $userData[0]);`

Comment: Problem seems to be that the site generates a new Session everytime an interaction is made. Its my first time working with the Session today so im a little lost.

Comment: It works now. Thanks so much for all your help. After 10 hours of learning and doing php i have no idea why it works now. But it does. Thanks so much for your time Richard!

Answer (score 1):

You call `checkSession` **BEFORE** you ever call `session_start()`, which means `$_SESSION`  will be empty, and your `isset()` calls will fail.

Comment: Thank you, I added it (also here in the code) still my checkSession() is not working.

Comment: then start standard session debugging: check `session_id()` at all stages, and see if the value stays the same. if it's changing, then you're getting new/empty sessions each time.

Comment: Hey, yes it is changing all the time. Maybe a start_session() too much?

Comment: you can check `session_status()` before calling session_start repeatedly. but the ID changing isn't a result of calling session_start(). it's a result of the client not sending back the session cookie, so the server issues a NEW one with a new(different) random ID. so... you need to check why the session cookie is being lost.

Comment: Okay, im trying to figure out the problem right now: I made a function: if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();}
$id = session_id();
echo $id;

Comment: It checks if there is a session before creating a new one. And still creates a new one everytime. I really dont get the problem right now.

Comment: the session cookie is getting lost. you need to check the path/expiration settings on that.

Comment: It works now. I really dont have a clue why. But one of the suggestions must have fixed the problem. Thank you very much for taking the time Marc. I appreciate it!